# Can I run a number of statements using a ternary operator in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an object named `MyObject`. This has a property Name.

Can I use the ternary operator like the following

```
string validSite = 'yahoo';
string invalidSite ='abc';
MyObject obj = new MyObject()
```

I want to perform a few statements in the true condition

```
valid ? ({ validSite; obj.Name = 'Test';})  : invalidSite
```

Is there a way to do this or do I need to use if-else?

Comment: Why not just use a plain `if`? Much more readable when the expressions get complex.

Comment: Readability and maintainability is miles better than short code. Use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** below are possible solutions to the situation mentioned above but they are not recommended. As [comment from @Hans Keﬆing on question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371070/can-i-run-a-number-of-statements-using-a-ternary-operator-in-c#comment112056426_63371070) I totally agree with using plain `if...else...` statement instead of `one liner` if your scenario is as simple as you mentioned in question.

Still this answer will help to know what could be the possible ways to achieve it and one can use it where this code fits best.

---

You can do something like below with `Func` define your statement inside `new Func(...)` and immediately invoke it with `()`.

```
var site = valid ? new Func<string>(() => { validSite; obj.Name = 'Test'; return obj.Name; })() : invalidSite;
```

Alternatively you can use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329.aspx) like below. Use `Lazy` instead of `func` and evaluate `expression` with `.Value` at the end.

```
var site = valid ? new Lazy<string>(() => { validSite; obj.Name = 'Test'; return obj.Name; }).Value : invalidSite;
```

---

I **recommend you to use [`Local function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)** which can provide `re-usability` of code if you need `same code` to `repeat` multiple times or else you can simply use `if...else...` if it fits to your requirement.

If you are using `C#7` or newer version then you can use [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). Inside this local function you can also use all local variables from parent function.

```
public void function Test()
{       
    var site = valid ? GetSite() : invalidSite; 
    
    string GetSite()
    {
        validSite; 
        obj.Name = 'Test'; 
        return obj.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: To downvoters can you please provide detail regarding to what is wrong with the solution?

Comment: I don't know how else to tell future readers "please don't do this".

Comment: @Sinatr, Thanks and I appreciate your comment.